# CLR user defined function parameter passing

Tags: sql, vb.net, clr

Im a SQL/VB person thats new to CLR.  Basically, I wanted to create a SQL function to pass an ID parameter, and return the corresponding data from a SQL table;

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Partial Public Class UserDefinedFunctions
    <Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess:= DataAccessKind.Read)> _
    Public Shared Function FalloutProfile(ByVal CRFNID As Integer) As SqlString

        Using connection As New SqlConnection("context connection=true")

            connection.Open()
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT RATE0ORIG FROM dbo.clsgfunc WHERE CRFNID=@pnum", connection)
            command.Parameters.Add("@pnum", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = CRFNID

            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            reader = command.ExecuteReader()

            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(reader)

        End Using

    End Function
End Class
```

I cant seem to get this working:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

any ideas?

Comment: can you give us more of the stack trace? just telling us there was a `NullReferenceException` doesn't give any leads

Comment: not familiar enough to get more than that.  The NullReferenceException is from SQL 08 R2 after I deploy the above CLR.  Hoping it was something obvious in the code.

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` means that something in your code is null when you try to access it. Can you try to debug locally?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an answer to this, it's hidden in the description of the [SqlContext.Pipe Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.pipe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

*An instance of SqlPipe if a pipe is available, or null if called in a context where pipe is not available (for example, in a user-defined function).*

So, if you try this from within a CLR procedure, it should work. From within a CLR function, it won't.